# Calling Hibernate session flush

Tags: java, hibernate

I store an entity, then I need to execute native query (it's done through `doWork`), and for successful execution of the query record[s] that represent entity must exist in database (to be more precise, it must be available within the same transaction), so I guess calling `flush` is valid under such circumstances...

I got confused by [hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Session.html#flush%28%29) that says flush

> must be called at the end of a unit of work, before committing the transaction and closing the session

Newer version http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/devguide/en-US/html_single/#d5e976 has example where `flush` is called in the loop.

Is it ok to call flush not just before committing ? If not, what is the alternative?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is OK to flush at any time. See the [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/objectstate.html#objectstate-flushing).